# MongoDB REST Interface

Tags: mongodb, rest, database, nosql

I have MongoDB database with HTTP REST Interface. I would like to extract one of the item from db. When i run for example this url : `http://localhost:80/dbname/collection/4fed0591d17011868cf9c982` i receive this data :

```
{
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5106e87b44ae0333fce5af69"
         },
         "nazwa_wydarzenia":"Opener",
         "data_rozpoczecia":{
            "$date":1356994800000
         },
         "data_zakonczenia":{
            "$date":1359759600000
         },
         "opis_wydarzenia":"Impreza muzyczna",
         "koordynaty":[
            {
               "szerokosc":23.4533,
               "wysokosc":52.1234234
            },
            {
               "szerokosc":26.4533,
               "wysokosc":55.1234234
            },
            {
               "szerokosc":28.4533,
               "wysokosc":57.1234234
            },
            {
               "szerokosc":30.4533,
               "wysokosc":58.1234234
            },
            {
               "szerokosc":31.4533,
               "wysokosc":59.1234234
            }
         ],
         "telefony_abonentow":[
            {
               "id_telefonu":"5106e87a44ae0333fce5af64",
               "numer_telefonu":"48520078426",
               "data_modyfikacji":{
                  "$date":1346450400000
               },
               "data_wejscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "data_wyjscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "czywObszarze":false,
               "czyWyslanoSMS":false
            },
            {
               "id_telefonu":"5106e87a44ae0333fce5af65",
               "numer_telefonu":"48658355395",
               "data_modyfikacji":{
                  "$date":1346450400000
               },
               "data_wejscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "data_wyjscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "czywObszarze":false,
               "czyWyslanoSMS":false
            },
            {
               "id_telefonu":"5106e87a44ae0333fce5af66",
               "numer_telefonu":"48248421652",
               "data_modyfikacji":{
                  "$date":1346450400000
               },
               "data_wejscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "data_wyjscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "czywObszarze":false,
               "czyWyslanoSMS":false
            },
            {
               "id_telefonu":"5106e87a44ae0333fce5af67",
               "numer_telefonu":"48951188325",
               "data_modyfikacji":{
                  "$date":1346450400000
               },
               "data_wejscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "data_wyjscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "czywObszarze":false,
               "czyWyslanoSMS":false
            },
            {
               "id_telefonu":"5106e87a44ae0333fce5af68",
               "numer_telefonu":"48299181345",
               "data_modyfikacji":{
                  "$date":1346450400000
               },
               "data_wejscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "data_wyjscia":{
                  "$date":59960905200000
               },
               "czywObszarze":false,
               "czyWyslanoSMS":false
            }
         ],
         "statystyki":{
            "ilosc_uczestnikow":3,
            "ilosc_wyslanych_smsow":2,
            "data_statystyki":{
               "$date":1359407227788
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "total_rows":1,
   "query":{

   },
   "millis":0
}
```

So, I am still wondering how to extract only values for

> "statystyki"

it would be

> "ilosc_uczestnikow" : 3

and

> "ilosc_wyslanych_smsow" : 2

Comment: Depends on what language you are using the rest interface from. What language are you using it from?

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to mention it! Javascript ;) jQuery.get() method.

Comment: What web server platform are you using? There might be a better way to extract just the info you want.

Comment: Tomcat Apache 7.0.34. I would also add that main application use this small piece of code is running on Spring Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is quite hard to see from the format you provided but in JQuery:

```
$.get('http://localhost:80/dbname/collection/4fed0591d17011868cf9c982', function(data){
    var statystyki = data.rows[0].statystyki;
}, 'json');
```

Will give you:

```
{ 
    "ilosc_uczestnikow" : 3, "ilosc_wyslanych_smsow" : 2, "data_statystyki" : { "$date" : 1359407227788 } 
}
```

In a variable which you can then use to just pick out again like:

```
statystyki.ilosc_uczestnikow
```

Which gives off the result of `3`.

That should work.